# Оцените правильность ответов на некоторые вопросы из теста по C++

Tags: c++, c++builder, visual-c++

Задали тест в университете. Из 100 вопросов оставил только те, в которых сильно сомневаюсь. Жирным выделил правильные, на мой взгляд, ответы. Как вы оцениваете правильность моих ответов?

1. Тип данных – это: **1. категория** 2. авторский класс 3. слово 4. выражение
2. Класс – это: 1. категория **2. авторский тип** 3. переменная 4. выражение
3. Функция описывает 1. состояние **2. поведение** 3. значение 4. обработку
4. Константа описывает **1. состояние** 2. поведение **3. значение** 4. обработку
5. Спецификация описывает **1. порядок работы** 2. файлы 3. функции 4. данные
6. Члены класса бывают **1. открытыми** 2. свободными 3. закрытыми 4. занятыми
7. Компиляторами являются: 1. С++ 2. Паскаль **3. Ассемблер** 4. Unix
8. Окно бывает: **1. главным 2. родительским 3. свернутым 4. активным**
9. Свойства визуальных компонентов: **1. left 2. right 3. top 4. bottom**
10. Область видимости локальных данных: 1. класс 2. файл 3. модуль **4. блок**
11. Файлы бывают: 1. буквенными 2. цифровыми **3. бинарными 4. логическими**
12. ! Разделитель свойств и методов С++: 1. запятая 2. точка 3. точка с запятой 4. пробел
13. ! В модуль С++ входят: 1. код формы 2. описание формы 3. заголовок формы 4. примечание формы
14. ! В проект С++ входят: 1. код проекта 2. описание проекта 3. заголовок проекта 4. примечание проекта
15. ! В приложение С++ входят: 1. код приложения 2. файл приложения

Последние четыре пока сложны для меня. Ответить не смог совсем.

Comment: Этот тест очень плохой. Определения понятий видимо придумывал ваш преподаватель, поэтому единственное место, где можно узнать правильный ответ, это конспекты его лекций.

Comment: Жуть(. 
Думаю, как-то так:
6 - 1,3
7 - 1,2,3
11- я сам теперь не знаю))) 2 3 наверное все таки
12 - 1
На счет это 15 полный П - 2 (исполняемый файл, как я понял)) )

на с++ не писал остальное не знаю ( (кто пишет на с++ конечно респект!)

Comment: @Михаил Мишин, напишите, пожалуйста название ВУЗ’а и факультета, где требуется решать подобные тесты.

Comment: И смех и грех) Сочувствую студентам, которые обучаются у таких профессоров!

Comment: @VioLet, Ивановский государственный университет. Факультет математики и компьютерных наук.

Comment: @NMD, спасибо.

Comment: Да. Тест ужасен. Более ужасными были практические задания, которые, слава богу, с горем пополам выполнил)

Comment: Общее замечание: я бы все вопросы привёл (в порядке уменьшения уверенности, если хочется), потому что люди часто не знают, что они не знают -- особенно, ценно найти ошибку у себя, если уверен, что прав.

Answer (score 10):

1. Вопрос выглядит безграмотным (по крайней мере с точки зрения терминологии) и крайне плохо сформулированным. Предположу, что вы ответили верно (хотя не могу отднозначно утверждать, что имел в виду автор этого вопроса
2. Также очень корявый вопрос. Но тут явно ответ верный
3. Аналогично п. 2
4. Тут судя по всему верным является только вариант 3
5. Непонятно, что подразумевается под словом "спецификация", поэтому ответ на этот вопрос знает только тот, кто его придумал.
6. Открытыми и закрытыми
7. Ничего из перечисленного компилятором не является. Однако возможно, что у придурка, составлявшего этот вопрос, иное мнение, поэтому без комментариев. Хотя ниже в комментариях ниже  есть предположение относительно того, что же имел в виду составитель вопроса.
8. В принципе, все вышеперечисленное может быть применимо к окнам.
9. Пожалуй, тут верно (однако непонятно, какое отношение это имеет к С++, как и предыдущий вопрос)
10. В С++ есть несколько  возможных типов областей видимости - глобальная область, область видимости пространства имен, область видимости класса, область видимости функции, область видимости блока кода. К каждому из этих типов за исключением первого, применимо понятие "локальная переменная"
11. Здесь, судя по всему, стоит отметить только третий вариант - что такое логические файлы, я не знаю. Хотя, как верно заметил [[@Алексей Шаповалов](/users/5138/%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2)](/users/5138/%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2), возможно, что "буквенные" файлы - тоже верный вариант. "Буквенных" файлов, разумеется, не существует, но есть текстовые, и, возможно, составитель вопроса и здесь блеснул своей самодельной терминологией. В общем, тут (как и во многих других случаях) правильность ответа зависит не от ваших знаний, а от настроения вашего препода
12. Еще одна странность. В С++ нет свойств (на уровне синтаксиса), а для методов нет специфических разделителей. Тело же метода ограничивается парой фигурных скобок, которые вряд ли можно отнести к разделителям. Если же речь о разделителях для инструкций, то это точка с запятой.
13. Черт, что такое "модуль С++"? Насколько я знаю, такого понятия вовсе не существует. Есть заголовочные файлы, есть файлы исходного кода, есть пространства имен, но модулей как таковых нет, поэтому непонятно, что автор вопроса подразумевает под этим термином. Как верно отмечено ниже, наверное определенный смысл у этого и следующего вопроса есть в контексте применяемой IDE. Но это уже конкретные детали.
14. Еще какая-то лажа - с точки зрения языка не существует "проектов C++" как таковых. Проект - это сущность исключительно IDE, а не языка. Если же речь о С++ builder и его проектах, то, скорее всего подразумевается, что верные варианты - это "код формы" и "заголовок формы"
15. Блджад, что такое "приложение С++" в контексте языка?

У меня есть серьезное опасение относительно элементарных познаний в С++ автора этого опроса. 
Если вам нужен этот язык, то искренне вам советую учить его не у тех, кто составляет подобный безграмотный бред

Comment: По поводу 9 - речь, вероятно, идет о C++ builder - там это актуально, соответственно 13 и 14 тоже, надо полагать, относится к этой IDE.

№11 - логические - точно нет, но насчет буквенных может быть. Учитывая "гениальность" автора этого вопроса - он мог так обозвать текстовые файлы.

№7 - тут явно автор имел ввиду 1, 2, 3. Ибо с точки зрения "знающих" преподавателей Бейсик - это интерпретатор, а Паскаль и Си - компиляторы. То что, на самом деле, это ЯП оставим на их совести. И да, мой совет Михаилу - учите язык сами, там, где вы его учите, многому вас не научат.

Comment: Вопросы найс)
12 - видимо, составитель имел ввиду точку с запятой)
13-14 - видимо, терминология, разумная в рамках какой-то IDE, на которой велось обучение))

Comment: @Алексей Шаповалов спасибо за пояснения относительно особенностей C++ Builder. Но, черт возьми, насколько же некомпетентно и искореженно подается учебный материал в этом вузе.

> видимо, терминология, разумная в рамках какой-то IDE, на которой велось обучение)) 

а вот за привязку языка к IDE стоит вообще от церкви отлучать

Comment: Огромное спасибо. Даже не ожидал такого.
Файл логический вот тут описан. http://shiva16.narod.ru/Unit22.htm
А если идти по компиляторам, то Ассемблер - есть такой компилятор. Совпадает с названием языка.

Comment: >Файл логический вот тут описан

это называется "смешались в кучу кони, люди"

>Ассемблер - есть такой компилятор

и гже же его можно увидеть?

Comment: В целом согласен, но всё же странно что-то.

2) Что означает «авторский» тип? Это тот, который написан не разработчиком компилятора? А классы системной библиотеки как?

3) Функция вовсе ничего не описывает, это кусок кода.

8) В зависимости от оконной системы. В Xfwm вроде бы не так.

9) В зависимости от графического фреймворка. В WPF не так.

Присоединяюсь к мнению о преподавателе. @Михаил Мишин: учите лучше сами, по документации и на практике. Меньше вреда будет.

Comment: @DreamChild, мне тоже кажется, что Ассемблер это компилятор. Из исходных файлов на языке ассемблера (тут, конечно же, надо бы уточнить какого именно, ну например, gas ([команда as в Linux](http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.18/as/index.html))) делает объектные файлы.

Comment: Вот ещё 4 вопроса. Тут я правильно ответил?
1. Функции подлежат: **объявлению определению** разрушению **применению**
2. Переменные подлежат: **объявлению определению разрушению применению**
3. Константы подлежат: **объявлению определению разрушению применению**
4. Объекты подлежат:** объявлению определению разрушению применению**

Comment: > мне тоже кажется, что Ассемблер это компилятор

@avp да, вы, разумеется, правы, что-то меня переклинило)

Comment: никто не мешает сделать для ассемблера интерпретатор. Вопрос 7 наверное нужно читать так: "для чего с перечисленного существуют компиляторы". Правда в этом случае правильными будут все 4 варианта:) (gcc- это компилятор под Unix и не только).

------------

Подобные вопросы нужно на Хэшкод выкладывать по другому. Показывать вопросы и правильные ответы, а потом уже предлагать угадать, почему автор задачника решил именно так и какие вещества мог принимать в данный момент.

Comment: @Михаил Мишин: Разница между «объявлением» и «определением» существует лишь в C и C++. Слово «применение» (использование) можно с натяжкой _применить_ ко всем четырём понятиям, хотя так никто не говорит. В языках с first-class-функциями функции вполне себе могут подвергаться «разрушению». (Или в .NET при выгрузке `AppDomain`'а.) С известной натяжкой можно считать, что стековые переменные «разрушаются» при закрытии фрейма. И так далее.

В общем, вопросы на знание конспекта, а не программирования.